# Visual Studio 2013 closes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I recently installed Visual Studio 2013, so I'm relatively new to it.  I'm trying to run the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World! ";
}
```

but the terminal that's supposed to open to display "Hello World" closes immediately and doesnt give me the chance to see whether it was printed.

The program outputs:

```
The program '[480] Project2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Also, I've read some previous posts that suggest to add system("pause") before the end of main(), however why is it that I need to do this in the first place? Is there something wrong with my Visual Studio?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is ok with your Visual Studio.
It is an expectable behaviour of your program.

First, you need to understand that Visual Studio doesn't somehow affect the process of program execution after it has been compiled and run. It shouldn't "pause the program" in the end of execution itself. So, if you run your application by clicking `F5` in Visual Studio or run it outside of Visual Studio as `exe`-file, you will get the same result.

Now the question is another: "why do console applications close right after the execution instead of pausing at the end and letting me read something"? The answer is that this is how console applications are supposed to be executed. It starts, executes some code and returns 0 (in a good case).
If they are run within a console, the results of execution will be seen in a console.
However, if they are run outside of console, as an application, they open the console, output something and close before you read anything.

For example, take the `runas` application.
Try openning a console (`Win+R` -> `cmd`) and type

```
runas
```

You will see a help explaining how to use `runas` application. Right after outputing this, it will close and the control will be returned back to `cmd.exe`. You will be able to run other applications.

Now, try to open it outside of console using `cmd` again (don't be afraid, it is absolutely safe):

```
%windir%\system32\runas.exe
```

The same information will be outputed to a console but you probably won't have time to read anything.

To sum up: your **Console** application should do something, output some information and close after it. That's how they work. However, during the development process you will have to put "pause", breakpoint or something else in the end of an application to see the results of execution.
As for me, the most convenient approach is inserting this line in the end of an application.

```
Console.ReadKey();
return 0;
```

You also can use `Ctrl+F5` to run an application in a console without debugging.
It will execute a `pause` console command which outputs 'Press any key to continue...' before closing. However, you won't be able to debug it.

Comment: Thank You!  I'm very knew to this, this was extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Debug > Start Without Debugging

> Ctrl + F5

Comment: finally, a simple and effective answer :)

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov Someone has just installed a Visual Studio at **the first time** and, most probably, he doesn't know how is that all working. He came here to **understand** why is it happening. Telling him something without explanation is not a best approach in this case. Next time, he will come here again asking "I clicked Ctrl+F5 but breakpoint is not working". People at SO are not competing in the shortness of an answer. Simplicity is not always good.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev valid points, Yeldar.Your answer is superbly elaborate. I'd only add a c++ standard library way of expressing `Console.ReadKey();`, since it looks as a .net API call and not standard c++

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this two lines:

```
system("pause>nul");
return 0;
```

Comment: I guess my question is why do I need to add those two lines? Shouldn't Visual Studio not be doing this?

Comment: Actually, just the first one should do it. You need to add them to be able to see the output. Otherwise the program starts, prints "Hello World" and then closes itself because it has no other statement to execute.